# Restrict access to Azure app (WebApi) only to another Azure app (daemon client)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered my REST Api project into my AzureAD so I can use AzureAD authentication. Lets call this app "*RestApi*".

I have also registered another console app, that will access this API. Lets call this "*ConsoleClient*".

How can I restrict access so **only** *ConsoleClient* will be able to access *RestApi*? I am able to set similar permissions for users (Enterprise apps -> Users and groups) but not for another Azure AD app.

Comment: You have to define app permissions in your API. My blog article has details on how to do that: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: I was able to set up application permissions. So by default every authenticated Azure app in my tenant is able to log into my API. I can't restrict apps on Azure side and I have to make custom authetication in code using given roles?

Comment: You have to check in the API that any access token has valid permissions in it. So yes, you have to check the roles claim in the case of app permissions.

Comment: @juunas, complie that in an answer to be properly voted!

Comment: Done :) added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define app permissions in your API. My blog article has details on how to do that: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Also, you have to check in the API that any access token has valid permissions in it. So, you have to check the roles claim in the case of app permissions.